# How can a scratch org be created through the Salesforce API?

Tags: rest-api, salesforcedx, api, scratch-org

I'm trying to create a developer tool that involves creating a scratch org programmatically. Is there a way to create a scratch org directly via the Salesforce API without using the sfdx CLI tool?

If so, which endpoint(s) can be used to create a scratch org?

Is the API that the sfdx CLI tool uses publicly accessible/documented?

Comment: https://jsforce.github.io/blog/posts/20170629-salesforce-dx-with-jsforce.html this is a JS wrapper but it's quite simple to see what's going on underneath the hood

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [ScratchOrgInfo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_scratchorginfo.htm) object in the SOAP API to create and delete Scratch Orgs. This means you'll need a WSDL and some language that supports SOAP in order to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The source code for sfdx is available via [GitHub](https://github.com/salesforcecli). Take a look there to see how it functions. No guarantee you'll find everything you need, but it's a good starting point.

Note that this was [announced by Salesforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2021/02/open-sourcing-salesforce-cli-update-feb-2021.html) earlier this year.